# When is Quotient topology by Group action Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

Let $G$ be a topological group and $X$ be topological space, and $\rho$ be a continuous action of the topological group $G$ on $X$. We know that $\pi$ projection of topological space onto quotient space is open.

Let $R=\{(x,y):x\sim y\}$

We know $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff iff $R$ is closed in $X\times X$

Let $O_x$ be the orbit of $x\in X $.

Is it true that If each $O_x$ is closed in $X$ then  $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff?

Or is there any other condition for Hausdorff using an Orbit of action?
It's in my notes but I don't know why it has to be true.

My attempt:

here, $R=\bigcup_{x\in X}  \{x\}\times O_x$
But I have no idea how to prove R is closed.

Edit :

If $G$ acts by homeomorphisms the quotient map $p: X \to X / G$ is always open (contrary to general quotient maps): this is because $V \subset X/G$ is open if and only if $p^{-1}(V) \subset X$ is open and $p^{-1}(p(U)) = \bigcup_{g \in G}gU$ is a union of open sets if $U \subset X$ is open. Therefore $X/G$ is Hausdorff if and only if the orbit equivalence relation is a closed subset of $X \times X$.

**Could someone please explain  $X/G$ is Hausdorff if and only if the orbit equivalence relation is a closed subset of $X \times X$.**

Comment: Check Tu's "Differentiable Manifolds", pages 73-76.

Answer (score 3):

Is it true that: If each $O_x$ is closed in $X$ then  $X/\!\sim$ is Hausdorff?

If each $O_x$ is closed in $X$ then $X/\!\sim$ has the property that each point is closed.  That does not imply that $X/\!\sim$ is Hausdorff.

Indeed, let $X$ be a non-Hausdorff topological space with every point closed (say, $T_1$ but not $T_2$).  Let $G = \{e\}$ be the trivial group, and $\pi$ be the trivial action.  Then ${X/\!\sim}\; = X$.

Comment: If $G$ acts by homeomorphisms the quotient map $p: X \to X / G$ is always open (contrary to general quotient maps): this is because $V \subset X/G$ is open if and only if $p^{-1}(V) \subset X$ is open and $p^{-1}(p(U)) = \bigcup_{g \in G}gU$ is a union of open sets if $U \subset X$ is open. Therefore $X/G$ is Hausdorff if and only if the orbit equivalence relation is a closed subset of $X \times X$.

Comment: Could you please explain what it means by orbit equivalence relation is closed